# How would I find how many rows in excel contain multiple unique values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, data-validation

I have a list of all buyers in our state with their account number and the zip code they live in. I'm tasked with finding out how many buyers live in each zip code.

```
|Account ID|Zip  |    
|   13     |40005|    
|   45     |40083|    
|   12     |40006|    
|   40     |40005|
```

Part of my issue stems from having the same zip code in multiple places due to having multiple unique buyers living in the same area. I have tried using the following but it wasn't quite what I wanted.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("zip",data))
```

Comment: use a pivot table

Comment: @ScottCraner How would you set up the pivot table when my columns are "zip" and "account ID"?

Comment: Put the zip in rows and in the values.  Change the value from sum to count.

Comment: @ScottCraner That works! Thank you.

Comment: There are functions like countif()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have been better as an answer not a comment.

So as SCOTT said.

Use a pivot table.

Highlight all the data (in this case account ID, and Zips), in headers (so you have them as labels).

Select insert pivot table.
Tick "zip"
Drag zip to Rows
Click the down arrow on "sum of zip", select field value settings, change sum to count.
Hey presto, you have a list of zip codes, with a count next to them.

I know just just pretty much wrote what was above, but it's an answer now!! So others can find it.